# binding to the srcset attribute not working with KnockoutJS

Tags: knockout.js, magento2

How can you bind to the `srcset` in **KnockoutJS**?

I've tried using the ["attr" binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html) from their documentation.

```
<picture>
    <source data-bind="attr: { srcset: require.toUrl('/Vendor_Module/images/mobile-version.png')" media="(max-width: 767px)" />
    <source data-bind="attr: { srcset: require.toUrl('/Vendor_Module/images/desktop-version.png')" />
    <img data-bind="attr: { src: require.toUrl('/Vendor_Module/images/desktop-version.png')/>
</picture>
```

The resulting markup is...

```
<picture>
    <source data-bind="attr: { srcset: require.toUrl('/Vendor_Module/images/card-mobile.png')" media="(max-width: 767px)" />
    <source data-bind="attr: { srcset: require.toUrl('/Vendor_Module//images/card-desktop.png')" />
    <img data-bind="attr: { src: require.toUrl('/Vendor_Module/images/card-desktop.png') src="https://example.com/static/version1527767610/frontend/vendor/theme/en_US/Vendor_Module/images/desktop-version.png" />
</picture>
```

Comment: ...and what's the result?

Comment: @Tomalak, just updated the question

Answer (score 1):

**(facepalm)**

I was just missing a `}` at the end of the ["attr" binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html).

So this...

```
<source data-bind="attr: { srcset: require.toUrl('/Vendor_Module/images/desktop-version.png')" />
```

became this...

```
<source data-bind="attr: { srcset:  require.toUrl('/Vendor_Module/images/desktop-version.png')}" />
```

Comment: I believe the `ko.expressionRewriting.preProcessBindings` function returns an empty string for this typo, resulting in a silent fail...